# Alternative to a nested struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I tend to use nested structs when I want to keep track of how many items I have in the inner struct. So I usually do the following:

```
typedef struct Product {
    char *name;
    int qty;
} Prods;

typedef struct Category {
    char *name;
    int qty;
    int prods_count;
    Prods *prod;
} Cats;
```

then I can access/free the data as:

```
Cats *cat = malloc(sizeof(Cats));
cat->prods_count = 10;
cat->prod = malloc(cat->prods_count, sizeof(Prods));
cat->prod[0].name = malloc(15);
strcpy(cat->prod[0].name, "Hello World!!!");
cat->prod[0].qty = 100;
for (i=0; i<cat->prods_count; i++)
    free(cat->prod[i].name);
...
```

I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this only with one `struct`?

Comment: I don't get why you'd want to roll these into one struct - a product and a category are separate concepts, it's *good* to have them as separate structs.

Comment: @Mac true. What he wants is a "is-a" graph of Product to Category map. X product is-of Y category.. something like that.

Comment: @Mac: I just thought that perhaps there was a simpler way. Based on the current answers, seems that's perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: You could literally nest the structures into each other. It would still be two, but one would be declared inside the other. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @jogojapan: No, I was looking to have only one struct. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I do not see any `malloc()` for `cat->prod[i].name`, but it is `free()`'ed in a loop -- is that correct and expected?

Comment: @Arun Saha: Question updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep an array for qty and an array for name, but this would be very cumbersome, as it takes away the logical relationship that having them in their own struct implies.

Nesting structs (and their object counterparts in object-oriented languages) is perfectly natural, and you should get accustomed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
typedef struct Category {
    char *name;
    int qty;
    int prods_count;
    Prods *prod;
    int * qty;
    char ** name;
} Cats;
```

But you now you have to malloc twice instead of once.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this: "you have to malloc twice". So far I malloc twice... Thanks

Comment: Instead of one malloc for Prods you have to so two; for qty and name.

Answer (score 0):

Your current setup is a good way to structure it. It is called [Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Aggregation).